# Checkable Layout hierarchy

Tags: android, listview

I use :

```
public class CheckableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable {

    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = { android.R.attr.state_checked, };

    private boolean mChecked;

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (mChecked != checked) {
            mChecked = checked;
            refreshDrawableState();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }

}
```

based on [this](https://developer.android.com/samples/CustomChoiceList/src/com.example.android.customchoicelist/CheckableLinearLayout.html) and i use it like this :

```
<com.example.components.CheckableRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/CheckableRelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_background_navigation_item"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigationDrawerItemImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/navigationDrawerItemTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/navigationDrawerItemImageView"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/navigationDrawerItemImageView"
        android:textColor="@drawable/selector_text_navigation_item"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

</com.example.components.CheckableRelativeLayout>
```

in a list item where selector_background_navigation_item defined like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/darkblue"></item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/sirinblue"></item>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/white"></item>
</selector>
```

and selector_text_navigation_item defined like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/white"></item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/lightblue"></item>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/lightblue"></item>
</selector>
```

Now, the problem is that the TextView Selector does not respond to the check events, while the CheckableRelativeLayout does, but both respond correctly to simple presses, whats the best way to fix this? maybe CheckableRelativeLayout missing some super call that handles its children checked state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding android:duplicateParentState="true" to the TextView did the trick!